# access to many2one fields

Tags: odoo, many-to-one

I have a many2one field like this

```
state = fields.Many2one ("ags.traffic.operation.state")
```

state has the following fields

```
name = fields.Char
sequence = fields.Integer
type = fields.Selection
```

in my view i have

```
<field name = "state" widget = "statusbar" clickable = "True" / >
```

how can i access those fields to set a default value?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to define the field that gets shown in the drop-down in your view in your model define `_rec_name` this tells odoo to display that field (in a drop down or in a many2many tag field) when a many2one or one2one relationship is created between that model and another model. for example if you want the sequence number to display in the drop down just set

`_recname = 'sequence'`

but by default odoo checks the model's field and if it finds a name field (just like you have defined in your model). it uses that as the default display name.

if you want to search records in odoo you can use the `search` method. please see the documentation for more information about the odoo ORM

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.browse

```
search(args[, offset=0][, limit=None][, order=None][, count=False])
```

but a typical example is

```
search_records = self.env['your.model'].search([('id', 'in', ids)])
```